# Подчеркивание текста изображением или градиентом, с переносом строк и анимацией при наведение?

Tags: css

Хотелось бы иметь возможность 1 решения для всех случаев подчеркивания текста (сложного картинкой или градиентом, с переносом строк и анимацией при наведение). На данный момент я использую 3 решения (как сократить?):

**1. Если нужно подчеркивание каждой строки,  с переносе текста и анимацией при наведение:**

```
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-style: solid;
text-decoration-color: red;
text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
text-underline-offset: X;
text-decoration-thickness: X;
```

Проблемы:

- Отсутствует возможность сложного подчеркивания изображением или градиентом.

**2. Если нужно сложное подчеркивание изображением или градиентом:**

Через `background-image`, пример: https://codepen.io/cassie-codes/pen/rNNGdmw

Проблемы:

- Отсутствует возможность анимации у `background-image`.

**3. Если нужно сложное подчеркивание изображением или градиентом, с анимацией:**

Через псевдо-элементы, пример: https://codepen.io/iam_aspencer/pen/qvNPBv

Проблемы:

- Отсутствует возможность переноса подчеркивания с переносом текста ну другие строки.

Comment: 1. обе ссылки на кодепен одинаковые. 2. Лучше оформить тут сниппетом.
3. с чего вы решили ,что background-image нельзя анимировать? сдвиг фона с помощью background-position прекрасно работает.

Comment: @Инквизитор ссылки поправил, на сколько я знаю, background-image не поддерживает анимацию.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под анимацией background-image? Плавный морфинг одной картинки в другую? Тогда да, невозможно. А вот смещение, трансформация, наложение фильтров - это вполне реально, ибо относится к свойствам background-position, background-size и т.п.

Comment: @Инквизитор подразумеваю "Отсутствует возможность анимации у background-image."

Comment: Логично. Анимация возможна в принципе для свойств, для которых существует промежуточное состояние. У фоновой картинки такого нет.  А вот у ее положения в элементе - есть, и анимация фоновой картинки возможна банально за счет сдвигов и трансформаций. Простейший пример - картинка с несколькими кадрами, которые циклично сдвигаются, в точности как в синематографе.

Comment: @Инквизитор к сожалению, анимация лишь положений элемента не достаточна, хочется плавно менять цвет/градиент и само изображение (старое>новое).

Comment: Цвет можно. Градиент тоже. Чтобы сработал с изображением, придется повозиться, ибо непонятно, что именно вы ждете от анимации. Если вас интересует плавное "перетекание" одной картинки в другую , как в мультике, то вам придется произвести раскадровку (создать ВСЕ промежуточные состояния изображения) и делать анимацию сдвигом кадров, как я уже писал. Если достаточно плавного исчезновения одного изображения и замены его другим, то это решаемо, но с костылями.

Comment: @Инквизитор предположим, я задал элементу при дефолтном состояние background-image: linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531), а при hover изменяю его background-image: linear-gradient(#d13531, #eb01a5) - градиент плавно не меняется, как менялся бы сплошной цвет

Comment: Просто градиенту надо кое-что указать :) См. ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анимация градиента (взято  с h.t.t.p.s://dev.to/afif/we-can-finally-animate-css-gradient-kdk и адапитровано для вашего случая):

```css
@property --c {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: red;
}

@property --e {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: blue;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: --c 1s, --e 1s;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--c), var(--e));
}

.box:hover {
  --c: green;
  --e: gold;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: [К-кроссбраузерность](https://i.imgur.com/7OgNQbo.png)

Comment: П - безразлична. Автор настаивал на принципиальной невозможности анимации градиента, я показал пример возможности. К тому же градиент практически всегда можно изменить так ,чтобы анимация создавалась за счет других свойств фона, типа background-position.